# Keep getting "AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: home" when running my Flask website

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

This one of my first questions on here so if any of this formatting is wrong please let me know. I have an issue in my Flask views.py where it is claiming that the functions are overwriting an exisiting enpoint:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/Meet_band')
def meet_band():
    return render_template('meet_the_band.html')

@app.route('/shows')
def shows():
    return render_template('gigs.html')
```

This is my views.py. Could it be due to my from app import app? I have read that circular imports could be the reason but not sure how to fix this. Any help would be great thanks! below are my **init**.py and run.py as well

app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('config')

from app import views
```

Comment: Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question. please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Please add your project structure. And also mention other necessary code.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies, not sure how to type in the project structure, but here is a link to the project https://github.com/josh-mccullough/James_Lynas_Band

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Flask version 0.10 you may have to downgrade to 0.9 to get this working.

I had a site running on 0.10 on one machine, but got the same error when running on a different machine with the same version of Flask.

It's very odd and I do not have time (or skills) to look further into it.